# Contra/Co Variance for a list of generic types assuming base interface inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, covariance

in .NET I have a three level inheritance using generics with a pattern like:

```
public interface IManager<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent 
{ 
    void Foo( TEvent mySpecificEvent ); 
    //... 
}

class Manager<TEvent> : IManager<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
class NumericManager<TEvent> : Manager<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent 
class SpecificNumericManager : NumericManager<ISpecificNumericEvent>
```

This way the specific managers can handle specific types with the hopes that I can hold several kinds of specific types in a list and tell them all to run `Foo(TEvent mySpecificEvent)` operations on their specific events as long as the event inherits from `IEvent`

Everything builds fine when but I try to treat my `SpecificNumericManager` as an `IManager<IEvent>` to add it to a `List<IManager<IEvent>>` I get a runtime error of:
"Unable to cast object of type `SpecificNumericManager` to type `IManager<IEvent>`"

Note my code is in VB but I have translated to C# hoping for more support, so if I goofed something small it might be explained by that.

I have experimented and I can successfully cast my `SpecificNumericManager<ISpecificNumericEvent>` to `IManager<ISpecificNumericEvent>` but just not directly to `<Manager<IEvent>>`

It seems like contravariance and covariance of generic types was coming up in my first swing at finding out what I can do to fix it, but I haven't found out that the trick is.

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How is `IManager<TEvent>` defined?

Comment: `public interface IManager<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
   {
      void Foo( TEvent mySpecificEvent );
      //...
   }`

Comment: Just because two types (say, `T1` and `T2`) exhibit a particular inheritance/implementation relationship, that *does not mean* that a generic type closed over those types (say, `G<T1>` and `G<T2>`) exhibits the *same* relationship. In general, there are *no* relationships between those types.

Comment: Even with the use of generic type constraints we can't enforce a relationship between T1 and T2?

Comment: You can't do this safely - if it were allowed you could do: `class OtherEvent : IEvent { }` and  `var l = new List<IManager<IEvent>> { new SpecificNumericManager() }; l[0].Foo(new OtherEvent());` and pass an instance of `OtherEvent` to `SpecificNumericManager.Foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>What you need is for you `IManager` to be covariant.</s>

```
interface IManager<out TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
```

That way this assignment becomes legal:

```
IManager<IEvent> manager = new Manager<IMoreSpecificEvent>();
```

Covariance, in the most basic sense, specifies that you don't care if the type parameter is more derived than the constraint for such assignment. That means that, among other things, nowhere in a covariant implementation (so in your Manager
You can read more about covariance in C# [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier).

EDIT:

Right, so this method:

```
void Foo(TEvent mySpecificEvent);
```

ruins our little plan here. Right now your `Manager` is not covariant, and for a good reason. Let's consider a list:

```
List<IManager<IEvent>> list;
```

and say that this assignment is legal (*it is not*, but let's pretend) :

```
IManager<ISpecificNumericEvent> manager = new SpecificNumericManager();

list.Add(manager);
```

What happens if we pass this list around to do some operations on the manager? Well, all we know is that a thing inside is of type `IManager<IEvent>`. That means that we should be able to feed it *any* `IEvent` into the `Foo` method, right?

```
class BaseEvent : IEvent {}

foreach(var manager in list)
{
    IEvent event = new BaseEvent();

    manager.Foo(event);
}
```

But since we have earlier assigned a `SpecificNumericManager` to the list, we're trying to call a method with a signature:

```
void Foo(TEvent event) where TEvent : ISpecificNumericEvent
```

with a `BaseEvent`, which does not implement `ISpecificNumericEvent`. Boom, the type system is destroyed in a fiery explosion, cats and dogs living together, mass hysteria.

This interface cannot be covariant for the reasons given above - C# simply disallows the bypassing of the type system earlier, disallowing a covariant assignment to`IManager<IEvent>`. For the same reasons a for-loop feeding events to generic `IManager<IEvent>`s would be a bad idea, because there is simply no idea of knowing whether a particular manager will be able to handle that particular event at compile-time. You need to think about what you're really trying achieve with that loop. Usually, when covariance/contravariance rules are broken, it's because the thing you want to do really does not make sense. If, however, you want to do some crazy stuff on types on a generic `IManager<IEvent>` list, then you won't have the type system on your side and will have to use reflection to achieve your insidious goals.

Comment: Since `IManager<TEvent>` only has one visible method and that method accepts `TEvent` as an input, it's difficult to see how *just* marking it as `out` is going to be the entire fix.

Comment: Oh, the `IManager`'s definition was not given while I was given this response, yes, right now you can't even mark this parameter type as covariant I'm afraid.

Comment: That makes total sense. Thanks for your time and great example. It isn't easy explaining that kind of stuff in a easily understandable way, but you pulled it off. I'll get back to the drawing board to see if I can achieve my goals without conjuring too many evil spirits.

Comment: @RyanDonahue - often in this sort of case you'll want to put a non-generic class/interface in higher up the hierarchy than the generic ones. That way you can still store a `List<IManager>` (note, non-generic here), but you then need to do runtime checks on each member of the list to determine if it's usable with the specific event you're currently processing.

Answer (score 1):

@V0ldek has already explained in detail why it happens. Basically, the inheritance relation `TDerived : TBase` does not propagate to `T<TDerived> : T<TBase>`.

A possible solution is to declare a non-generic base type:

```
public interface IManager
{
    void Foo(IEvent nonSpecificEvent);
    //... 
}

public interface IManager<TEvent> : IManager
    where TEvent : IEvent
{
    void Foo(TEvent mySpecificEvent);
    //... 
}
```

This allows you to declare a list as

```
List<IManager> _list;
```

... being compatible with all kinds of managers deriving directly or indirectly from `IManager` and being generic or not.

This results in 2 overloaded versions of `Foo`.

You can hide a member when accessed through types other than the defining interface with explicit implementation:

```
class Manager<TEvent> : IManager<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
{
    public void Foo(TEvent mySpecificEvent)
    {
        //...
    }

    // Explicit implementation
    void IManager.Foo(IEvent nonSpecificEvent)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In VB this can be done by declaring it private

```
Private Sub Foo(nonSpecificEvent As IEvent) Implements IManager.Foo
```

---

```vb
Public Interface IManager
    Sub Foo(nonSpecificEvent As IEvent)
End Interface


Public Interface IManager(Of TEvent As IEvent)
    Inherits IManager

    Overloads Sub Foo(mySpecificEvent As TEvent)
End Interface


Class Manager(Of TEvent As IEvent)
    Implements IManager(Of TEvent)

    Public Sub Foo(mySpecificEvent As TEvent) Implements IManager(Of TEvent).Foo
    End Sub

    ' Hidden  implementation
    Private Sub Foo(nonSpecificEvent As IEvent) Implements IManager.Foo
    End Sub
End Class
```